# Gitlab-shell throwing 404 request for internal api requests?

Tags: git, version-control, ssh, gitlab

If I do `ssh -T git@my-server`
I am getting

```
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

If I do `git clone git@gitlab.advantage4me.co:matthew/dummy.git`
I am getting

```
Cloning into 'dummy'...
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Which is strange since the key exists, but looking in the gitlab-shell.log It is giving me

```
API call <GET https://my-server/api/v3/internal/discover?key_id=1>
failed: 404 => <{"message":"404 Not found"}>.
```

Using git clone via https is working fine.

Now I know it's not an issue with having the wrong url configured since from the same server I can do (note I **copy/paste**'d the `my-server` to ensure no typos).

```
wget https://my-server/api/v3/projects
?private_token=zogmVjiVBZcEn39Vx4qK
```

What would be causing this, gitlab seems to think it is running fine?

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.8.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... 
Api / core ... repository is empty
Matthew Hailwood / dummy ... ok
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.8.6
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
projects have namespace: ... 
Api / core ... yes
Matthew Hailwood / dummy ... yes
Projects have satellites? ... 
Api / core ... can't create, repository is empty
Matthew Hailwood / dummy ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.3)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question as I encountered the same error. After a lot of troubleshooting, this has worked for me:

1. Clear all currently set authorized keys:

   sudo -u git -H bin/gitlab-keys clear
2. Reboot and setup GitLab shell:

   sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:setup RAILS_ENV=production
3. Login to GitLab with the browser and remove RSA keys from your
   user profile
4. Add you RSA key again to your user profile

Source:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-23219136